# MbUnit SetUp & Teardown thread safety?

Tags: concurrency, selenium, mbunit

First time poster, long time lurker. Figured it's about time I start getting actively involved. So here's a question I've spend all weekend trying to find an answer to.

I'm working on writing a bunch of acceptance tests using Selenium and MbUnit, using the DegreeOfParallelism attribute that MbUnit offers.

My Setup and Teardown methods respectively starts a new and destroys a selenium session, based on the assumption that the method is run in isolation of the context where the test that's gonna be invoked, is about to be run.

However, I'm seeing something that the Teardown method is not guaranteed to be run in the correct context, resulting in the state of another test, which is being run, to be changed. This is manifesting itself as the Selenium session of a random test gets shut down. If I simply prefix and suffix my test bodies with the code(Both 1-liners), everything works correctly.

Is there any way to ensure that the Setup and Teardown methods does not run in the incorrect context/thread?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some sample code that illustrates the issue?

Comment: @Chadk there are known issues with using DegreeOfParallelism that haven't been fixed yet.  See this bug report that may or may not be related: http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=732